# How to handle get and post requests with a single line in routes.rb in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to handle get and post requests in a single line.

I have a one definition(test) in controller(accounts). This definition can be called either get request or post request. But i would like to define this in single line in routes.rb file.

Now i am doing like,

resources :accounts do

```
 collection do

  get 'test'

  post 'test'

 end
```

end

which is worst case. If i have more definitions in a controller i need to mention two time for each and every definition.

Please provide me solution.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the `get`, `post`, `put`, `patch` and `delete` methods to constrain a route to a particular verb. You can use the `match` method with the `:via` option to match multiple verbs at once:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

You can match all verbs to a particular route using via: :all:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all
```

**For Example:**

```
match '/list' => 'products#products_list', :as => 'products_list' , via: [:get, :post]
```

**[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)**

Comment: When i am declaring this in routes.rb file showing error like " Unexpected ':' " in netbeans.

Comment: see the example in my answer.. replace , to: with =>

Comment: Getting this exception ...
undefined local variable or method `via' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fc2fb7f0a88>

Comment: You probably need to replace `via: [...]` with `:via => [...]` too. Worth mentioning which version of ruby and which version of rails you are using in cases like these.